# How to fix unknown GitLab runner failed issue for Android multi module gradle project?

Tags: android, gradle, java-8, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am new to GitLab CI-CD and trying to set up simple CI-CD for my android multi-module project.
Please note that the same CI-CD works for a simple android demo project.

My project uses Java 8 and compile on Android API v29 and runs on Linux runner with kubernetes executer.

I have been trying different things(like: disabling the grade daemon and increasing the jvmruntime memory size) to make it work based on many stack over flow suggestions. but I could not get to the bottom of the issue.

It would be really grateful if some one can help me out to fix this issue.

**Error:
**

```
section_end:1684489071:get_sources
[0Ksection_start:1684489071:step_script
[0K[0K[36;1mExecuting "step_script" stage of the job script[0;m[0;m
[32;1m$ cd Code/Android[0;m
[32;1m$ export GRADLE_USER_HOME=$(pwd)/.gradle[0;m
[32;1m$ chmod +x ./gradlew[0;m
[32;1m$ ./gradlew assemblePmcdev --stacktrace[0;m
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5.1-all.zip
> All compiling of project goes here
section_end:1684490052:step_script
[0Ksection_start:1684490052:cleanup_file_variables
[0K[0K[36;1mCleaning up project directory and file based variables[0;m[0;m
section_end:1684490052:cleanup_file_variables
**[0K[31;1mERROR: Job failed: pod "runner-xxxxxx-project-xxxxx-concurrent-xxxxx" status is "Failed"
**[0;m
```

Tried setting up the jvmargs

org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit -XX:GCHeapFreeLimit=20 -XX:GCTimeLimit=60

Tried using : image: alvrme/alpine-android:android-29-jdk8